# How to implement 3d reconstruction algorithms

Tags: matlab, opencv, graphics, 3d, projective-geometry

I have been doing some study on 3d reconstruction from multiple 2d views of late. Most of what i have read focuses on fundamental matrix , epipolar geometry and other theoretical principles of the subject. Let us say that given two images, I know how to calculate the 3d point corresponding to each 2d point.

My question here is:

1. Which software or libraries should I use for displaying the 3d model?
2. How do I represent 3d model ?

I do know that MATLAB or OpenCV can be used, but i did not find anything that discusses how to do it.

Comment: check out the SFM module in OpenCV https://github.com/amroamroamro/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/sfm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [disparity map](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html) in OpenCV. You can use to generate depth maps (similar to those you get from - let's say - a Kinect but less accurate obviously). Each pixel in a disparity map represents the distance to the object based on the differences between the two frames used to generate the map.

There is an [example in the OpenCV samples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py) where you can get an idea how it's done.

As for the representation of the 3D data I would suggest PCL (Point Cloud Library) or any other library that works with point clouds because...Well, this is a sort of a practice nowadays. Point clouds allow you to apply various algorithms on the space data (including feature matching, merging, transformation etc.) plus the ability to generate meshes. PCL for instance has - if I remember correctly - at least 3 ways of generating a mesh from a point cloud (the NURBS module is sadly still experimental and buggy).

Comment: How can i use it if i have to implement my own algorithm from scratch?

Comment: The best way to implement your own stuff is probably to read some papers (some are usually mentioned in the OpenCV docs when an algorithm there is based on such a material) and take a look at source code of OpenCV. After all it's open source. :3